# Where I went wrong and got an unwanted reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to apologize for my bad English - but there was no one to turn to.

I had begun to etch a printed circuit board and used 100ml. 3% H2O2, 2 tablespoons of citric acid, 2 tablespoons  NaCl.
After insertion of the printed circuit board - start reaction and the liquid turned blue, but in the middle saw that is less quantity and add hot water and the reaction stopped.
I noticed there was dirty on the circuit board and I removed it with a carpet knife. It immediately became red in contact with the liquid.
I poured the liquid into a plastic box and dipped a washed carpet knife and go to the pharmacy to buy H2O2

But I made a mistake because I bought 30% H2O2. I made a new liquid with 200ml. H2O2 and citric acid and NaCl. The PCB reaction was much faster. After I finished and pulled out the PCB , I wanted to see if more honey would be deposited, and I took the same knife I had dipped into the front solution and immediately got wet and the knife became black. A reddish froth floated on top of the surface. I went to wash the printed circuit board with water and heard some noise. I came back and some smell terrible and my eyes were red, I was breathing hard while I was throwing the liquid out and blowing.

The first day my eyes were watered and my sun was irritating, and in the shade everything was fine. The second day the sunlight did not irritate me, but when I looked at the light, I see something about the lamps that comes out when there is evening fog and looks at the lamp. On the third day I'm better and the vision returns.

What chemical reaction has occurred when:
H2O2 + citric acid + NaCl + Cu + Fe (I guess there are other substances in the mock knife)

Comment: There are way too many compounds with the sum formula $\ce{C6H8O7}$ for us to even attempt answering just from this.

Comment: 1 - Hydrogen peroxide 30%   , 2- Citric acid , 3-sodium chloride

Comment: I doubt there was some specific reaction. The peroxide simply decomposed rapidly, the bubbling threw H2O2 + citric acid in the air, and you inhaled that. Very unpleasant. Just dilute the peroxide previously in future, and you should be fine.